# Read a csv file to arrays

Tags: java

I'm working on a TSP problem and i've to read the x-y coordinates of my country's cities but when i try to do that i've faced an array out of bounds exception, i want to take x coordinates into array and y coordinates into other one, any Ideas, thanks.
package tsp;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tsp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] arr = new String[4000000];
        String fileName = "EG - Copy1.csv";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while(true){
                String xcoord = inputStream.next();
                arr = xcoord.split(",");
                double op = Double.parseDouble(arr[0]);
                double opy = Double.parseDouble(arr[1]);
                System.out.println(op+"****"+opy);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *Curious:* What is the point of `new String[4000000]`?

Comment: You didn't show the file content, but the code would indicate that it contains nothing but coordinates. Are you sure there aren't also **city names in the file**? You know, names with spaces and without commas, which will totally break your reading logic, because `New York` is two `xcoord` values and `split(",")` on the values `New` and `York` will fail when you do `arr[1]`.

Comment: Avoid spaces in file names.

Answer (score 0):

If the statement `xcoord.split(",")` does not find a comma returns an array of one element.

This latter raise an array out of bounds exceptions when you try to read from `arr[1]`.

BTW, it's worth nothing that you allocate a so big array:

```
String [] arr = new String[4000000];
```

Because the statement `xcoord.split(",")` reassign to `arr` a new array each time.

Answer (score 0):

There are some line of your file that are not well formatted. You can change your code as follow to process only the well formatted line.

```
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            String [] arr;
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String xcoord = inputStream.nextLine();
                arr = xcoord.split(",");
                if (arr.length == 2) {
                   double op = Double.parseDouble(arr[0]);
                   double opy = Double.parseDouble(arr[1]);
                   System.out.println(op+"****"+opy);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: why `arr` should be null?

Comment: but when i modify my code i got another exception "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" @MigSena

Comment: You are writing an infinite loop because you don't break the loop anywhere in the code.

Comment: Try again now to see if you still have an exception.